# Function $f(x,y)=2e^{-xy}$ is differentiable $(x,y)=(0,1)$ but can't prove limit $\frac{o(\Delta x,\Delta y)}{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}$ =0

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

$f(x,y)=2e^{-xy}$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f=-2e^{-xy}*y$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f=-2e^{-xy}*x$

These partial derivatives are continuous, so function is differentiable on $\mathbb R^2$

Consider this method:

Suppose I want to check the differentiability at point $T=(0,1)$ using this method:
$f(0+\Delta x,1+\Delta y)-f(0,1)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(0,1)*\Delta x+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(0,1)*\Delta y+o(\Delta x,\Delta y)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(0,1)=-2$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f=0$

$f(0+\Delta x,1+\Delta y)-f(0,1)=2e^{-\Delta x(1+\Delta y)}-2$

$2e^{-\Delta x(1+\Delta y)}-2+2\Delta x=o(\Delta x,\Delta y)$

We now need to show:

$$\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2e^{-\Delta x(1+\Delta y)}-2+2\Delta x}{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}=0$$
I can't solve this limit. Wolfram alpha returns "limit doesn't exist". Why can't we prove the differentiability this way even though the function is differentiable?

Comment: I get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%282+exp%28-x%281%2Ba+x%29%29-2%2B2x%29%2F%28x+sqrt%281%2Ba%5E2%29%29)

Comment: Hint: $e^{-\Delta x(1+\Delta y)}=1+(-\Delta x(1+\Delta y))+\frac{1}{2}(-\Delta x(1+\Delta y))^2+o((\Delta x(1+\Delta y)^3)$